# How to display error message when the user clicks on other tabs instead of the active tabs

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-tabs, noty

I have five tabs out of which the first tab is the active tab.On page load when the user clicks on any other tab rather than the first tab an error message should be displayed to the user using noty plugin that he should 'first click on the first tab' which is the active tab.When the user clicks on the first tab then the second tab must be enabled but not third and fourth,similarly when the user clicks on third tab then the fourth tab must be enabled and so on till the last tab.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.noty.packaged.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul id="mytabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="active">
          <a href="#first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-home"></i> First tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="disabled disabledTab second" ><a href="#second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Second tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#third" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Third tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#fourth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Fourth tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#fourth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Fifth tab
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade active in " id="first">
          <h2>First tab</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade disabled" id="second">
        <a href="javascript:show_create_case_msg();">
          <h2>Second tab</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="third">
          <h2>Third tab</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="fourth">
          <h2>Fourth tab</h2>
      </div>
       <div class="tab-pane fade" id="fifth">
          <h2>Fifth tab</h2>
      </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can achieve this by writing simple jquery. At start disable all tabs except first tab and then on click of any tab check whether the previous tab is already clicked or not. if not then give the message else activate that tab by keeping next tabs disabled

Answer (score 0):

Add a class `.disabled` to all the tabs in the html, except for the first one. Then add the following code:

```
$(".disabled").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     show_create_case_msg();
});

$(".tab-pane:not(.disabled)").click(function(){
    $(this).next().removeClass("disabled");
});
```

Comment: when i click on the second tab on page load then it is showing me error but it is displaying the contents of the second tab it should not go into the second tab unless the first tab is clicked.

Comment: `preventDefault()` should cancel the click and not run your function that the click triggers

Comment: create a fiddle and I'll add my code to it and show you how it works

Answer (score -1):

I would try to look it up in the concept beeing used in 
http://www.jquery-steps.com/

it has tabs there, you could block the navigation between tabs, and know on which tab you are.